# "One and half week" or "One and half weekS"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What's more correct when talking about 1.5 things?

Should we consider them as singular or plural?

For example:

- > **singular form**:  One and half week
- > **plural form**: One and half week**s**

Comment: I very recently read an article about an elderly Chinese woman who had only **one and a half tooth** and I thought that sounded strange. Would you like me to link the article?

Comment: I googled and I found a lot of both ways (one and a half tooth and one and a half teeth)

Comment: Then post the examples IN your question, please. You've been a member for two years, show the **research**. (Retracted upvote)

Comment: Possible duplicate - why and how?

Comment: Because it's a question about the plurality of "*point something* things".

Comment: Are you asking about the adjectival "noun adjunct" usage before the main noun? For that, it's singular (and usually hyphenated): *This is a **one-and-a-half-week** course*. For adjectival *clauses*, it's pluralised: *This course is **one and a half weeks** long*, or *The course lasts **one and a half weeks**,* etc.

Comment: @stangdon I'm not convinced this is a duplicate, if the OP could actually include a real life example where the singular form was used that would change significantly the question. (Hint, hint Industrious!!) If you don't post an example, I will but in a separate question, and I will also explain where my confusion lies.

Comment: Too late, it's been put on hold as a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

Better is to deal with such cases in following way,

> One week and a half

This removes the confusion.

However, as of your question, I believe "One and a half weeks" will be grammatically correct. 
***Anything bigger than 'one' is plural.***
I think that answers your question.

As of what I know, at many places, people have used "one and a half week" or "one and a half month" though in my opinion, they are 'grammatically' incorrect.

Comment: This is definitely not "better."   I don't know anyone who would phrase it that way.  "One and a half weeks" would be the standard way of saying it

Comment: [*Slowly raise the injector levels back to **point five grams** per second.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22back+to+point+five+grams%22) It's not that anything ***bigger*** than 'one' is plural - *all values **except** 'one' are plural*.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't say it's better. I said that it would be better to use it in this way if you want to remove this confusion..

Comment: @HassanAshas "I didn't say it's better, it said it would be better"  Um, OK.